# How to translate this SQL (or similar) to Criteria JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, criteria

I have this SQL and need to parse to Criteria JPA. I read than I can't use UNION in JPA, so I need a similar solution.

I have 3 tables (with same fields) and need to union for print in datatable.

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, project_id, start_date, end_date, 'cs' FROM construction_shares
    UNION
    SELECT id, project_id, start_date, end_date, 'ips' FROM intervention_pr_shares
    UNION
    SELECT id, project_id, start_date, end_date, 'is' FROM intervention_shares
) AS t ORDER BY START_DATE ASC;
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Criteria JPA dont support UNION, you can try two options.

1. Create a native query and execute from entityManager with a List of POJOS as result.
2. Throw 3 Querys like this:

SharesPojo:

```
private Integer id;
private Integer projectId;
private Date startDate; 
private Date endDate

public SharesPojo(Integer id, Integer projectId, Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

DAO:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<SharesPojo> csQuery = cb.createQuery(SharesPojo.class);
Root<ConstructionShares> csRoot = csQuery.from(ConstructionShares.class);
csQuery.multiselect(
    csRoot.get(ConstructionShares_.id)
    csRoot.get(ConstructionShares_.projectId)
    csRoot.get(ConstructionShares_.startDate)
    csRoot.get(ConstructionShares_.endDate)
);

CriteriaQuery<SharesPojo> ipsQuery = cb.createQuery(SharesPojo.class);
Root<InterventionPrShares> ipsRoot = ipsQuery.from(InterventionPrShares.class);
ipsQuery.multiselect(
    ipsRoot.get(InterventionPrShares_.id)
    ipsRoot.get(InterventionPrShares_.projectId)
    ipsRoot.get(InterventionPrShares_.startDate)
    ipsRoot.get(InterventionPrShares_.endDate)
);

CriteriaQuery<SharesPojo> isQuery = cb.createQuery(SharesPojo.class);
Root<InterventionShares> isRoot = isQuery.from(InterventionShares.class);
isQuery.multiselect(
    isRoot.get(InterventionShares_.id)
    isRoot.get(InterventionShares_.projectId)
    isRoot.get(InterventionShares_.startDate)
    isRoot.get(InterventionShares_.endDate)
);

List<SharesPojo> unionList = new ArrayList<>();
unionList.addAll(em.createQuery(csQuery).getResultList());
unionList.addAll(em.createQuery(ipsQuery).getResultList());
unionList.addAll(em.createQuery(isQuery).getResultList());
```

Comment: Criteria solution can work... but if i want to order by startDate and get only 10 first results, for example?

Comment: effectively that's a problem of this implementation.

You still have the native option.

It would also be to test the performance of doing the complete search without filters and filtering the list with stream and lambdas from java 8 to get the first 10 ordered.